# pointer in different processes were pointing to same address

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, operating-system, multiprocessing, multicore

I made a code with a switch to enable multi core feature .
I ran two different run 
1st - with single core 
2nd - with two cores

both were running with same exec and in the same machine in different terminals. I had to debug something. I was debugging parallel with both run, while debugging I found that "one same pointer in both run were pointing to same address" .

I know shared memory concept when we use fork , but here I was running two different process.

how Is this possible and what is the concept behind it .

Comment: Be more specific please, e.g. what cores do you mean, what operating system etc.

Comment: Because that's a [virtual memory address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), not a physical one.

Answer (score 2):

You are not specifying an operating system, but typically processes have independent address spaces.   What you are probably seeing are two pointers which happen to have the same value, but actually referring to each process' own memory space.

Protected mode OSs often remap physical memory into new address spaces for the user level programs.